# Python/Pywinauto CurrentTime==Given Time until Statement is True but it's always false

Tags: python, datetime, time, pywinauto

Expected Behavior
Check if CurrentTime == GivenTime(via input)
if Statement is True click Button

Actual Behavior
Checks if CurrentTime is GivenTime but if I check the bool even tho for example Current and GivenTime are both 13:29:50
bool is still False and the loop just continues.

```
from pywinauto import Application
import time
from pywinauto.timings import Timings
from datetime import datetime
from _strptime import _strptime
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title_re=u'Website', timeout=100)
Timings.after_clickinput_wait = 0
STime = input('insert STime:')
STime2 = datetime.strptime(STime,'%H:%M:%S')
print(type(STime2))
CurrentTime= datetime.now()
while STime2 != CurrentTime:
        CurrentTime = datetime.now()
        print("%s:%s:%s" % (CurrentTime.hour,CurrentTime.minute,CurrenTime.second))
        time.sleep(1)
else:
      app.Website.child_window(title='Button' , control_type="Button").click_input()
```

this is one variant i have tried but it doesent recognize the else because it cant break the while loop because the statement STime2 != CurrentTime is always True so the Current Time is never the STime2 even if it should.
The second variant is:

```
from pywinauto import Application
import time
from pywinauto.timings import Timings
from datetime import datetime
from _strptime import _strptime
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title_re=u'Website', timeout=100)
Timings.after_clickinput_wait = 0
STime = input('insert STime:')
STime2 = datetime.strptime(STime,'%H:%M:%S')
flag = True
while flag is True:
        CurrentTime=datetime.now()
        print("%s:%s:%s" % (CurrentTime.hour,CurrentTime.minute,CurrenTime.second))
        time.sleep(1)
        Time = CurrentTime == STime2
        if Time is True:
        flag = False
        app.Website.child_window(title='Button' , control_type="Button").click_input()
```

I dont get an Error but what it does is, it outputs me the currentTime so i can see the Time where the Time i typed in and the CurrentTime should be the same but it does nothing and just ignores the  if or else code of the variants.
i already got suggested that input is String and the CurrentTime is datetime.datetime but now I changed the input to datetime.datetime and it still doesent work.. anybody got an idea how to make it work?
i have also tried it with `if (CurrentTime == STime2):` still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You're working with `datetime` objects, but only providing the time of day in one of them. Python is providing a default date for the rest.

```
from datetime import datetime

STime = input('insert STime:')
STime2 = datetime.strptime(STime,'%H:%M:%S')

CurrentTime= datetime.now()

print(STime2)
print(CurrentTime)
```

Output:

```
insert STime:9:26:00
1900-01-01 09:26:00
2022-08-22 09:25:22.675953
```

The current time is never going to be equal to `1900-01-01 09:26:00`. You need to either get just the time of day from each `datetime` object, or have the user input both the date and time.

Either way, check the values you are comparing (either in your debugger or using `print` statements like I did here) to make sure they could reasonably be expected to be equal.